# How to match the returned hash with the posted hash in payumoney payment gateway (JSP module)?

Tags: jsp, encryption

I have to integrate payumoney payment gateway into my organization's website. Since our application has been developed using JSP so we choose to use the JSP kit provided by payumoney. The problem I am getting during test is that the posted hash and the returned hash do not match. I am providing you both the codes one for sending the digital order file(payuform.jsp) and the digital response file (success_payumoney.jsp) here for your kind debugging where I am wrong. Please excuse me for giving the whole code.

payuform.jsp

```
            <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
            <%@ page import="java.security.*" %>

            <%!
            public boolean empty(String s)
                {
                    if(s== null || s.trim().equals(""))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            %>
            <%!
                public String hashCal(String type,String str){
                    byte[] hashseq=str.getBytes();
                    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
                    try{
                    MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
                    algorithm.reset();
                    algorithm.update(hashseq);
                    byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();



                    for (int i=0;i<messageDigest.length;i++) {
                        String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                        if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append("0");
                        hexString.append(hex);
                    }

                    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){ }

                    return hexString.toString();

                }
            %>
            <%  
                String merchant_key="JBZaLc";
                String salt="GQs7yium";
                String action1 ="";
                String base_url="https://test.payu.in";
                int error=0;
                String hashString="";



                Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
                Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<String,String>();
                    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) 
                {
                        String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();

                        String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);

                    params.put(paramName,paramValue);
                }
                String txnid ="";
                if(empty(params.get("txnid"))){
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    String rndm = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt())+(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
                    txnid=hashCal("SHA-256",rndm).substring(0,20);
                }
                else
                    txnid=params.get("txnid");
                    /*udf2 = txnid;*/
                String txn="abcd";
                String hash="";
                String hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
                if(empty(params.get("hash")) && params.size()>0)
                {
                    if( empty(params.get("key"))
                        || empty(params.get("txnid"))
                        || empty(params.get("amount"))
                        || empty(params.get("firstname"))
                        || empty(params.get("email"))
                        || empty(params.get("phone"))
                        || empty(params.get("productinfo"))
                        || empty(params.get("surl"))
                        || empty(params.get("furl"))
                        || empty(params.get("service_provider"))
                    )

                        error=1;
                    else{
                        String[] hashVarSeq=hashSequence.split("\\|");

                        for(String part : hashVarSeq)
                        {
                            hashString= (empty(params.get(part)))?hashString.concat(""):hashString.concat(params.get(part));
                            hashString=hashString.concat("|");
                        }
                        hashString=hashString.concat(salt);


                         hash=hashCal("SHA-512",hashString);
                        action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
                    }
                }
                else if(!empty(params.get("hash")))
                {
                    hash=params.get("hash");
                    action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
                }
            %>

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>-----</title>
            <!-- // Stylesheets // -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ajax.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/service.js"></script>

            <!-- bootstrap framework files -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <script src="../../ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../../bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            var hash='<%= hash %>';
            function submitPayuForm() {

                if (hash == '')
                    return;

                  var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
                  payuForm.submit();
                }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body onLoad="submitPayuForm();">
            <div style="border:#999999 1px solid; margin:20px auto; width:700px;">
                <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <form action="<%= action1 %>" method="post" name="payuForm" class="form-horizontal">
                        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<%= merchant_key %>" />
                              <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<%= hash %>"/>
                              <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<%= txnid %>" />
                             <!-- <input type="hidden" name="udf2" value="<%//= txnid %>" />-->
                              <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" />
                <h1>Payu Money Payment Gateway</h1>           
                <span style="color:#FF0000; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">All Fields are Mandatory</span>
                <br /><br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Amount" class="control-label col-xs-2">Amount:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input name="amount" value="<%= (empty(params.get("amount"))) ? "" : params.get("amount") %>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FirstName" class="control-label col-xs-2">First Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<%= (empty(params.get("firstname"))) ? "" : params.get("firstname") %>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Email" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8"><input name="email" id="email" value="<%= (empty(params.get("email"))) ? "" : params.get("email") %>" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Phone" class="control-label col-xs-2">Phone:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input name="phone" value="<%= (empty(params.get("phone"))) ? "" : params.get("phone") %>" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="productinfo" class="control-label col-xs-2">Product Info:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input name="productinfo" value="<%= (empty(params.get("productinfo"))) ? "" : params.get("productinfo") %>" size="64" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FirstName" class="control-label col-xs-2">Success URI:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input name="surl" value="<%= (empty(params.get("surl"))) ? "" : params.get("surl") %>" size="64" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FirstName" class="control-label col-xs-2">Failure URI:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input name="furl" value="<%= (empty(params.get("furl"))) ? "" : params.get("furl") %>" size="64" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                          <% if(empty(hash)){ %>
                        <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/>
                        </div>
                        <% } %>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

success_payumoney.jsp

```
            <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
            <%@ page import="java.security.*" %>

            <%!
            public boolean empty(String s)
                {
                    if(s== null || s.trim().equals(""))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            %>
            <%!
                public String hashCal(String type,String str){
                    byte[] hashseq=str.getBytes();
                    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
                    try{
                    MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
                    algorithm.reset();
                    algorithm.update(hashseq);
                    byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();



                    for (int i=0;i<messageDigest.length;i++) {
                        String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                        if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append("0");
                        hexString.append(hex);
                    }

                    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){ }

                    return hexString.toString();

                }
            %>
            <%
            String status = request.getParameter("status");
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
            String txnid = request.getParameter("txnid");
            String posted_hash = request.getParameter("hash");
            String key = request.getParameter("key");
            String productinfo = request.getParameter("productinfo");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String salt = "GQs7yium";

            Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
                Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<String,String>();
                    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) 
                {
                        String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();

                        String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);

                    params.put(paramName,paramValue);
                }

            String retHashSeq = "salt|status|udf10|udf9|udf8|udf7|udf6|udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key";

                    String[] hashVarSeq=retHashSeq.split("\\|");

                        for(String part : hashVarSeq)
                        {
                            retHashSeq= (empty(params.get(part)))?retHashSeq.concat(""):retHashSeq.concat(params.get(part));
                            retHashSeq=retHashSeq.concat("|");
                        }

                   String hash = hashCal("SHA-512", retHashSeq);

                   if (hash != posted_hash) {
                        out.print(hash+"<br/>");
                        out.print(posted_hash+"<br/>");
                       out.print("Invalid Transaction. Please try again");
                       }
                   else {

                      out.print("<h3>Thank You. Your order status is "+status+"</h3>");
                      out.print("<h4>Your Transaction ID for this transaction is "+txnid+"</h4>");
                      out.print("<h4>We have received a payment of Rs. "+amount+"Your order will soon be shipped.</h4>");

            }         
            %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In success_payumoney.jsp you should use

```
if (!hash.equals(posted_hash)) {
```

instead of

```
 "if (hash != posted_hash) {"
```

And "salt" isn't sent as request parameters you must add it to "retHashSeq"

Here is the code

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.security.*"%>

<%!
        public boolean empty(String s)
            {
                if(s== null || s.trim().equals(""))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        %>
<%!
            public String hashCal(String type,String str){
                byte[] hashseq=str.getBytes();
                StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
                try{
                MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
                algorithm.reset();
                algorithm.update(hashseq);
                byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();



                for (int i=0;i<messageDigest.length;i++) {
                    String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                    if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append("0");
                    hexString.append(hex);
                }

                }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){ }

                return hexString.toString();

            }
        %>
<%
        String status = request.getParameter("status");
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
        String txnid = request.getParameter("txnid");
        String posted_hash = request.getParameter("hash");
        String key = request.getParameter("key");
        String productinfo = request.getParameter("productinfo");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String salt = "GQs7yium";

        Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
            Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<String,String>();
                while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) 
            {
                    String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();

                    String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);

                params.put(paramName,paramValue);
            }

        String retHashSeq = "status|udf10|udf9|udf8|udf7|udf6|udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key";

                String[] hashVarSeq=retHashSeq.split("\\|");
                retHashSeq=salt+'|';
                    for(String part : hashVarSeq)
                    {
                        retHashSeq= (empty(params.get(part)))?retHashSeq.concat(""):retHashSeq.concat(params.get(part));
                        retHashSeq=retHashSeq.concat("|");
                    }

               retHashSeq = retHashSeq.substring(0,retHashSeq.length()-1);
               String hash = hashCal("SHA-512", retHashSeq);

               if (!hash.equals(posted_hash)) {
                    out.print(hash+"<br/>");
                    out.print(posted_hash+"<br/>");
                   out.print("Invalid Transaction. Please try again");
                   }
               else {

                  out.print("<h3>Thank You. Your order status is "+status+"</h3>");
                  out.print("<h4>Your Transaction ID for this transaction is "+txnid+"</h4>");
                  out.print("<h4>We have received a payment of Rs. "+amount+"Your order will soon be shipped.</h4>");

        }         
        %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine by changing key and salt.

```
<%@page import="java.security.MessageDigest"%>
<%@page import="java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException"%>
<html>
<body>
<%
String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
String productinfo= request.getParameter("productinfo");
String txnid = request.getParameter("txnid");
String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String key = "JBZaLc";
String salt = "GQs7yium";
String status = request.getParameter("status");
String r_h =request.getParameter("hash");
String hashString="";
String udf1 =request.getParameter("udf1");
String udf2 =request.getParameter("udf2");
String udf3 =request.getParameter("udf3");
String udf4 =request.getParameter("udf4");
String udf5 =request.getParameter("udf5");
String p_Id = request.getParameter("payuMoneyId");
String additionalCharges = request.getParameter("additionalCharges");
out.println("Your paymnet with Payment ID is :" + p_Id + "is ");

 String hash;
 String email = request.getParameter("email");
 if(status.equals("success")){
 if(additionalCharges!=null){
 String hashSequence = additionalCharges+"|"+salt+"|"+status+"||||||"+udf5+"|"+udf4+"|"+udf3+"|"+udf2+"|"+udf1+"|"+email+"|"+firstname+"|"+productinfo+"|"+amount+"|"+txnid+"|";


  hashString=hashSequence.concat(key);
  out.println(hashString);
  hash=hashCal("SHA-512",hashString);
  out.println(hash);
  if(r_h.equals(hash)){
  out.println("Successfull with additiona charges");
  out.println("Transaction details:");
  out.println("Amount:"+amount);
  out.println("additionalCharges:"+additionalCharges);
  out.println("Status of Transaction:"+status);}

  else {
  out.println("Transaction details:");
  out.println("Amount:"+amount);
  out.println("additionalCharges:"+additionalCharges);
  out.println("Status of Transaction:"+status);
                    }
            }
            else {
            String hashSequence = salt+"|"+status+"||||||"+udf5+"|"+udf4+"|"+udf3+"|"+udf2+"|"+udf1+"|"+email+"|"+firstname+"|"+productinfo+"|"+amount+"|"+txnid+"|";


        hashString=hashSequence.concat(key);
                    out.println(hashString);
                    hash=hashCal("SHA-512",hashString);
                    out.println(hash);
        if(r_h.equals(hash)){
             out.println("Successfull");
                    out.println("Transaction details:");
                        out.println("Amount:"+amount);
        out.println("additionalCharges:"+additionalCharges);
        out.println("Status of Transaction:"+status);}

        else{ out.println("failure");
                    out.println("Transaction details:");
                        out.println("Amount:"+amount);
       out.println("additionalCharges:"+additionalCharges);
                        out.println("Status of Transaction:"+status);}
            }   
    }else {out.println("Transaction details:");
                        out.println("Amount:"+amount);
out.println("additionalCharges:"+additionalCharges);
                        out.println("Status of Transaction:"+status);
                    }
%>
<%!
 public String hashCal(String type,String str){
    byte[] hashseq=str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try{
    MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
    algorithm.reset();
    algorithm.update(hashseq);
    byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();



    for (int i=0;i<messageDigest.length;i++) {
        String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
        if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append("0");
        hexString.append(hex);
    }

    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){ }

    return hexString.toString();


}
%>
</body>
</html>
```